# cms pages not displaying properly on production website magento 1.8.10 [solved]

Tags: magento-1.8, server-setup

I'm having a magento 1.8.10 website on more servers, local, dev, staging and production servers, what I'm experiencing is that I'm trying to display the cms pages into the production website as the same in local, dev and staging. Once I go into the production pages I call a product group to display wrapped in divs which not appears; it seems to appear just the list of products look liking that there's an error in the list.phtml, everything is sepcified in the related cms pages, the databases are the same on each servers except the base url as you can easly imagine. Is there anything that could not be specified in the server settings or in the magento settings? I'm walking in the dark at the moment, let me know if you have any advice for it.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not 100% clear, can you rephrase and perhaps attach a few images of what the problem is so we can assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sorted out this problem, it was very strange to have same db and same data on different servers with this behavior, the problem was in a php error in the list.phtml not detected in dev and staging, this may be due to a different version of php on the different servers, so for everyone will have some sort of similar issue, please look at the server configuration. Thanks for the help.